# Get text under mouse click

Tags: jquery

I have a div that contains multiple lines of "free" text.

```
<div id="ItemQueue">&nbsp;
    <b>ADDED</b><br />
    102<br />
    103
</div>
```

When a user clicks on one of these text items such as 102 or 103, I need to get the text under the mouse where clicked within the div. My attempt is below however, this returns all of the text in the div not just the text that is under the mouse.

```
var queue = $('#ItemQueue');
queue.click(function (e) {
    alert($(e.target).text());
});
```

Comment: What do you mean by "get text under mouse click"? Do you want to get a word separated by spaces, a phrase?

Comment: My mistake @MilindAnantwar, the div name is ItemQueue in this case. I have edited my original post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('#ItemQueue').contents().wrap('<span/>')

$('#ItemQueue > span').click(function () {
    alert($(this).text());
});
```

Comment: Does this create spans within the BoardQueue element? Nice approach, I've not seen that one before

Comment: I really liked this approach. Since my div text is a parsed json object, I ended up just adding the span tags during parsing and then using $(varname).children('span').click(... to get the actual text. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Personally I'd split them into paragraphs/headers

```
<div id="ItemQueue">&nbsp;
    <h1 class="Clickable">ADDED</h4>
    <p class="Clickable">102</p>
    <p class="Clickable">103</p>
</div>
```

Then I'd use the JQuery

```
$('.Clickable').click(function(){
   alert($(this).html());
});
```

Answer (score 1):

i think its better to use **class** like this :

**HTML :**

```
<div id="ItemQueue">&nbsp;
    <b class="span">ADDED</b><br />
    <span class="span">102</span><br />
    <span class="span">103</span>
</div>
```

**JQUERY:**

```
$('.span').click(function(){
   alert($(this).html());
});
```

Comment: @Liath yes but this is what i wrote. i think simple codes exactly are the same. +1 for you because of your speed :)

Comment: Fair enough - great minds, just looked odd! :-) Upvote is much appreciated - unfortunately I'm at my daily cap so can't return the favour :-(